# CF7: Redirect to another URL if submission error

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created a form using the Contact Form 7 plugin for WordPress.

My form looks like this:

```
<label> User Name*
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Email Adress*
    [email* your-email] </label>

[submit "Register"]
```

I can detect if someone trying to use the same email address (already registered) via this tutorial, https://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=904

But, WHILE showing the error message, how can I let the page redirect him to another URL after some amount of time? For example to "/homesite/?para="

Maybe I need to do something with this code

```
if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
        $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
    }
}
return $result;
```

But I don't know how should I amend those code. Please help me.

Comment: To make it clear, I want to redirect them to a "welcome back" page, so that their data will not store again into my MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using DOM Events. CF7 has custom DOM events, which can be used to redirect users to other page. Since you want to redirect when form data is invalid, you will need to use `wpcf7invalid` event.

> `wpcf7invalid` — Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, but mail hasn’t been sent because there are fields with invalid input.

A quick example:

```
function my_awesome_cf7_custom_events () { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {
            if ( 'FORM_ID' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {//<===replace FORM_ID with form id
                location.replace('https://your-new-url/');
            }
        }, false );
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_awesome_cf7_custom_events' );
```

Replace FORM_ID with your form id, and set your url.

[More about CF7 DOM events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to carry query parameter = your-name to the next URL and user must filled in the field first. Is it possible?